# VS: how to automatically add log for every created function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, logging

I am using VS in the project. I want to add a log for every function.

For example:

```
void function()
{
  LOG_FUNCTION_IN();

  // do something
  
  LOG_FUNCTION_OUT();
}
```

Adding `LOG_FUNCTION_IN/LOG_FUNCTION_OUT` manually is inconvenient.

Is it possible to add the two statements automatically when the function is created? Can macro in *Visual Studio* do it? Or can *Visual Assist* plug-in do it?

Comment: Use a class passing in `__func__` to the constructor - which will log entry and use the destructor to log exit on destruction, see - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you for your kindly reply. But, I need to add `LOG_FUNCTION_IN/LOG_FUNCTION_OUT` for every method. Not only constructor and destructor.

Comment: for gcc its so easy... simply add -finstrument-functions for compile and every entry and exit will be result in a  call to __cyg_profile_func_enter __cyg_profile_func_exit. I searched a bit for VS but did not find something which results in the same...

Comment: Visual Studio currently does not have this function, I suggest you go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion) to report the request.